# Dynamic text print in python

Tags: python

Printing text that updates, for example a clock, in python. Ive read some threads about this but they only worked if the program prints out one line. What i am trying to do is, i already have a sort of terminal in python that accepts commands and executes them, it runs in a while loop, now if i wanted to make a clock in the top right corner of the terminal, but preserve what the user is typing and the output of previous commands, how would i do that?

P.S.: Sorry for bad formatting, in typing this from my phone

Comment: You might want to have a look at `prompt-toolkit`, and Mike Pirnat's PyGotham talk "Dungeons and Dragons and Python", where he builds an app rather like what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily update stdout with this:

```py
print('foo', end='')
print('\rbar', end='', flush=True)
```

This example prints out `foo` and then changes the line to `bar`

Comment: yes i understand that, my question is if there is any way to do this for multiple lines and not changing some without clearing the terminal and printing the whole thing again

Comment: Then you might want to see `curses` - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html